# How to take limited amount of related (many to one ) objects. django

Tags: django, django-models, one-to-many, django-orm

So I have these three models:

```
class Database(models.Model):
    fields...

class DatabaseFieldsToCheck(models.Model): 
    data_base = models.ForeignKey(Database, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sql_requests_to_check")

class Result(models.Model):
    result = models.ForeignKey(DatabaseFieldsToCheck, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="results")
```

so my relation looks like this
**Database ---many---> DatabaseFieldsToCheck ---many--> result**
So in my view i want to get for each database only last 10 results.
how can i do it?
should i try raw sql ? or mby write some data transfer objects ?

Comment: Last 10 results regardless of which `DatabaseFieldsToCheck`? Or last 10 per `DatabaseFieldsToCheck`?

Answer (score 0):

in you model paste afield by which you can order acc to time for that first paste this field all in your model of which you want to fetch result

```
created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,editable=False)
```

then in your views

```
def viewname(request):
    result = Result.objects.order_by('-created')[:10]
    return render(request, 'home.html',{'result':result})
```

Comment: i want to be able to call result from database instance.